# Multiple codable object types out of a single JSON return

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, codable

My dilemma is I'm receiving two different object types from one table in a JSON response.  Here is an example of the response of both types in a return.

```
"supplementaryItems": [
    {
        "header": "Doodle",
        "subHeader": "It's a drawing.",
        "slideID": 4,
        "imageName": null,
        "textItems": null,
        "sortOrder": 0
    },
    {
        "header": "Cell Phones",
        "subHeader": "No phones please",
        "slideID": 8,
        "imageName": "welcome_icon_cellphones",
        "textItems": ["first","second","third"],
        "sortOrder": 1
    }
]
```

What we're hoping to do is create two different types of objects here.  A `textOnlyItem`, and a `imageWithTextItem`.

Is there a way to create one as a subclass or extension that can be keyed off of a `Bool` defined by whether `imageName` is `null` or not?

Thanks for any help all.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need two different objects. Just declare `imageName` and `textItems` as optional, this handles the `null` case.

You can simply check whether `imageName` is `nil`

```
let jsonString = """
{"supplementaryItems": [
{
"header": "Doodle",
"subHeader": "It's a drawing.",
"slideID": 4,
"imageName": null,
"textItems": null,
"sortOrder": 0
},
{
"header": "Cell Phones",
"subHeader": "No phones please",
"slideID": 8,
"imageName": "welcome_icon_cellphones",
"textItems": ["first","second","third"],
"sortOrder": 1
}
]
}
"""
```

---

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let supplementaryItems : [SupplementaryItem]
}

struct SupplementaryItem : Decodable {
    let header : String
    let subHeader : String
    let slideID : Int
    let imageName : String?
    let textItems : [String]?
    let sortOrder : Int
}

do {
    let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    for item in result.supplementaryItems {
       if let imageName = item.imageName {
           print(imageName + " has text items")
       } else {
           print(item.header + " has no text items")
       }
    }
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: The problem is I do need multiple objects.  In the project there are huge numbers of each instance (previously they were using hardcoded data source, and there were two objects.  Now there is one return for both objects) so we need to pull each object type out, or else restructure a ton of their app.  That's a possibility if it isn't possible to pull them apart at this level.

Comment: Then you have to write a custom initializer.

Answer (score 0):

I actually like vadian's approach, of one type. But I gather that would require significant refactoring in your situation.

The other approach is to just use `JSONSerialization` and build your heterogeneous array manually. `JSONSerialization` isn't deprecated, it just doesn't do it automatically like `JSONDecoder`.

Another approach is to use `JSONDecoder`, writing custom initializer that tries to decode it as `ImageItem`, and if that fails, try decoding it as `TextItem`:

```
protocol SupplementaryItem {
    var header:    String    { get }
    var subHeader: String    { get }
    var slideID:   Int       { get }
    var sortOrder: Int       { get }
    var textItems: [String]? { get }
}

struct TextItem: SupplementaryItem, Codable {
    let header:    String
    let subHeader: String
    let slideID:   Int
    let sortOrder: Int
    let textItems: [String]?
}

struct ImageItem: SupplementaryItem, Codable {
    let header:    String
    let subHeader: String
    let slideID:   Int
    let sortOrder: Int
    let textItems: [String]?
    let imageName: String
}

struct ResponseObject: Decodable {
    let supplementaryItems: [SupplementaryItem]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case supplementaryItems
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        var container = try values.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .supplementaryItems)
        if container.count == nil {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Expected array for supplementaryItems")
        }
        var items = [SupplementaryItem]()
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            if let item = try? container.decodeIfPresent(ImageItem.self), let imageItem = item {
                items.append(imageItem)
            } else {
                let textItem = try container.decode(TextItem.self)
                items.append(textItem)
            }
        }
        supplementaryItems = items
    }
}
```

Then:

```
let string = """
    {
        "supplementaryItems": [
            {
                "header": "Doodle",
                "subHeader": "It's a drawing.",
                "slideID": 4,
                "imageName": "foo",
                "textItems": null,
                "sortOrder": 0
            },
            {
                "header": "Cell Phones",
                "subHeader": "No phones please",
                "slideID": 8,
                "imageName": "welcome_icon_cellphones",
                "textItems": ["first","second","third"],
                "sortOrder": 1
            }
        ]
    }
    """

let data = string.data(using: .utf8)!

let json = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseObject.self, from: data)
print(json)
```

I'm not convinced this is any better or worse than just using `JSONSerialization`, but it's another approach.

Comment: Hey Rob, thanks for the response.  I don't think the exact functionality I was hoping for is technically possible after some researching.